# AudioKit Draw line for volume level in AKNodeOutputPlot

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am using AudioKit to display recording level with AKNodeOutputPlot. I have to display a line which will say proper audio level to record audio.
I have to draw line at -10 dB. How can I achieve that? this is my sample code (Swift 4).

```
 AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
    // Patching
    outputPlot.node = mic
    micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
    micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)
    
    // Microphone monitoring is muted
    micBooster.gain = 0 // Silent
    recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: micMixer)
    if let file = recorder?.audioFile {
        player = try? AKAudioPlayer(file:file)
    }
    player?.completionHandler = playingEnded
    
    moogLadder = AKMoogLadder(player)
    
    mainMixer = AKMixer(moogLadder, micBooster)
    
    AudioKit.output = mainMixer

    if isMicPresent {
        AudioKit.stop()
        AudioKit.start()
    }
    currentSeconds = 0
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
```

The output looks like following
[image]

Whereas I want to display graph like this line on 10 dB.

[image]

How can I draw line at 10dB and graph like waveform?

Comment: Hey I kinda need solution for this too.. 
Anyluck ?

Comment: how did you draw this redline ??

Comment: fgure it out ever?